# no edit filter configuration button in logcat

Tags: android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtznY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWTio.png)

I am not sure my there is no edit filter configuration button in logcat. Somebody knows how to fix this?

I have tried searching online but seems no solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to install newest version of Android Studio.

This feature is applied in the last version which named Electric Eel.